# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException at TimetableMainActivity$GetXML.onPostExecute

Tags: java, indexing, bounds, out

im having an issue with my code. Im passing data from one activity to another, with no issue, but when i try to show that schedule im choosing from a spinner, it gives me an index out of bounds exception

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class TimetableMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final String[] page_titles = new String[]{"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"};

final String[] hours = new String[]{"9", "10", "11", "noon", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"};

private String[][] days;
private int pos;
private String source = null;

public static ArrayList<String> schedule = new ArrayList<String>();

List<Map<String, String>>[] list = new List[5]; // Mon - Fri
Map<String, String> map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (!isNetworkAvailable())
        new AlertDialog.Builder(TimetableMainActivity.this).
                setTitle("Error").setMessage("No Network Connection").
                setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();
    else {
        new GetXML().execute("");
    }
}

public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

private class GetXML extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String src = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        source = extras.getString("Name");
        try {
            URL url = new URL(source);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            src = readStream(con.getInputStream());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return src;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (src == null)
            new AlertDialog.Builder(TimetableMainActivity.this).
                    setTitle("Error").setMessage("No Schedule Found").
                    setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();
        else parseXML(src);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_timetable);


            days = new String[5][10];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                    int k = i * 10 + j;
                    days[i][j] = schedule.get(k);
                }
            }


        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            list[i] = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        int count = hours.length;

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("time", hours[i]);
                map.put("description", days[j][i]);
                list[j].add(map);
            }
        }

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int today = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 2;

        pos = 0;
        if (today >= 0 && today <= 4)
            pos = today;

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.ViewPager);
        CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(TimetableMainActivity.this, list);
        PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = findViewById(R.id.pager_tab);

        int color = Color.parseColor("#33b7ee");
        pagerTabStrip.setTabIndicatorColor(color);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}

public void parseXML(String src) {
    try {
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(src);
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(sr);

        int token = xpp.getEventType();
        while (token != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (token == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if (xpp.getName().equals("cid")) {
                    token = xpp.nextToken();

                    if (xpp.getText() == null)
                        schedule.add("");

                    if (token == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                        schedule.add(xpp.getText());
                    }
                }
            }

            token = xpp.nextToken();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String readStream(InputStream in) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String line = null;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

That is the second activity that is passed the data from the first activity, which is here:

```
public class ScheduleMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final static String[] programs = { "Select Program", "Architectural",
        "Civil", "Geomatics", "Computing Systems", "Biomedical",
        "Instrumentation", "Electrical (Power)",
        "Telecommunications", "Chemical Processing", "Industrial", "Mechanical",
        "Manufacturing", "Petroleum" };

final static String[] years = { "Select Year", "First", "Second", "Third" };

String p = new String();
String y = new String();
String cid = new String();
String loc = new String();



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_schedule);

    Spinner spinner_p = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_p);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ScheduleMainActivity.this,
            R.layout.spinnerrow, R.id.spinner_id, programs);
    spinner_p.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    spinner_p.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            switch(pos) {
                case 1 : cid = "ae"; break;
                case 2 : cid = "ce"; break;
                case 3 : cid = "ge"; break;
                case 4 : cid = "cs"; break;
                case 5 : cid = "eb"; break;
                case 6 : cid = "ei"; break;
                case 7 : cid = "ep"; break;
                case 8 : cid = "te"; break;
                case 9 : cid = "cp"; break;
                case 10: cid = "in"; break;
                case 11: cid = "me"; break;
                case 12: cid = "mm"; break;
                case 13: cid = "pe"; break;
                default: break;
            }
            p = programs[pos];
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    Spinner spinner_y = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_y);
    ArrayAdapter<String> y_arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ScheduleMainActivity.this,
            R.layout.spinnerrow, R.id.spinner_id, years);
    spinner_y.setAdapter(y_arrayAdapter);

    spinner_y.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            y = years[pos];
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.schedule);

    b.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(v == b) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    v.setAlpha(.3f);
                }
                else {
                    v.setAlpha(1f);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(p.equals("Select Program") || y.equals("Select Year"))
                new AlertDialog.Builder(ScheduleMainActivity.this).
                        setTitle("Error").setMessage("No Program/Year selected").
                        setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();
            else {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M");
                String month_name = monthFormat.format(cal.getTime());

                int month = Integer.parseInt(month_name);
                int selectedYear = 0;

                if(y.equals("First"))
                    selectedYear = 1;
                else if(y.equals("Second"))
                    selectedYear = 2;
                else if(y.equals("Third"))
                    selectedYear = 3;

                int semester = 0;
                if(month >= 9 && month <= 12) {
                    semester = 3 * selectedYear - 2;
                }
                else if(month >= 1 && month <= 4) {
                    semester = 3 * selectedYear - 1;
                }
                else {
                    semester = 3 * selectedYear;
                }

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                sb.append("http://branko-cirovic.appspot.com/etcapp/timetables/timetable_"); sb.append(cid); sb.append(semester); sb.append(".xml");
                loc = sb.toString();

                Toast.makeText(ScheduleMainActivity.this,"You Selected : "
                        + loc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(ScheduleMainActivity.this, TimetableMainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Name", loc);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Please if anyone can fix my issue or tell me how to fix it, I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: The exception will tell you exactly which line of code is causing a problem AND the index it is trying to access. Obviously you are trying for a negative index or an index >= the number of items in a collection.

Comment: so the issue was actually with the URL i was trying to pass to the second activity was given to me, wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was actually with the URL i was trying to pass to the second activity was given to me, wrong.

I've gotten it to work correctly now, by putting the 'Bundle extras' into the try statement in the second activity